# Full Copula View using Meucci's Full Flexible View

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, distribution, random-variables, entropy-pooling

I'm currently setting up an "Investment Framework" that should allow the following steps:

1. Investment Committee (IC) has to decide on probabilities for 4 different market states. I have historical data for each of the distinct market states. This historical data will be probability weighted as input in step 2.
2. Generate 1 million data points for all 43 portfolio assets based upon the moments (up to kurtosis) of the weighted market state. This will be use as input for step 3.
3. The IC can now specify views on all the different moments (for example that the correlation between asset 4 and asset 17 has to be >0.8) using Meuccis Algorithm.
4. Once all views are created, run the algorithm and get all 4 moments as input into a portfolio optimizer.

I cannot solve the following points:

- **Step 2:** If I specify all 4 moments for 43 assets, I end up with 178'364 `(n + (n*(n+1))/2 + (n*(n+1)*(n+2))/6 + (n*(n+1)*(n+2)*(n+3)/24)` unique views for the copula. I tried to generate random multivariate distributions using the mean and covariance and then adjust the sample using Meuccis algorithm and all moments as "views" as described by him [(see page 20 of his paper)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1213325). Using Scipys optimizer didn't yield any results (beside an out of memory error...). I even tried using only mean, variance, skew and kurtosis (no covariance, no coskewness and no cokurtosis, but this failed as well...
   Is it even feasible to optimize after so many parameters? Or is it worth the time to rebuild everything and use another optimiser (like pyomo)?
  *If we can solve this, it would allow to generate multivariate samples from existing distributions using higher moments which is an unsolved problem in math as far as I'm informed*
- **Step 4:** Meucci shows how to calculate the mean as well as covariance after the optimisation [(Matlab Code)](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21307-fully-flexible-views-and-stress-testing). I would be interested in the coskewness and cokurtosis matrix as well. Does anybody know how to?